# How to write firebase emulator setting by Typescript?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-tools

Now I am using local firebase emulator by typescript.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as serviceAccount from './service-account.json';

const firebaseAdmin = admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount as admin.ServiceAccount)
});
```

But this above code doesn't work properly.
So then, Front app always connects cloud firebase. But I want to connect local emulator.
please tell me how to write.

Comment: So you want it to connect to a local host of firebase?

Comment: Hi, Artrix. Yes, I want to connect local emulator.
But this above code can't work well. Please teach me how to write.

Comment: From what I know, firebase isn't self hostable